# Ada state in Image processing and Machine learning

Tags: c++, c, machine-learning, image-processing, ada

I do some math projects with Ada. After that, I found that Ada can interface with low-level, and high-performance languages like Fortran and C/C++. It is also good at concurrence processing (I don't know it same with parallel processing or not). Now, I want to do Machine learning and Image processing projects. The speed and memory are very critical for me and must be optimized.

My questions are:

Is Ada has a good library for Machine learning or Image processing or both? How is the speed of math performance in Ada rather than python or Matlab?

Is interfacing between Ada kernel and C/C++ for Machine learning, and Image processing lead to good speed? How about using the property of concurrence processing?

Can Ada have an interface with Julia and Python?

Comment: The best answers regarding performance is to benchmark the code.  Search the internet for "Ada benchmarks versus C++".

Comment: Profiling and benchmarking depend on the efficiency of the algorithm and the implementation of the algorithm.  Also, taking advantage of the platform hardware, such as cores and caches to name a few.

Comment: FWIW, FORTRAN and Algol have excellent math performance.  Prolog and LISP are good for machine learning.  Probably, the best language is the language you are most familiar with.

Comment: if it can use C++ code, it can interface with OpenCV. -- any number crunching uses a GPU anyway

Comment: See [*C or Ada for engineering computations? (closed, deleted, hidden)*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2662397/230513); moderators: please consider voting to undelete/reopen. Quoting T.E.D, "I once saw a guy get his gnat "Hello world" implementation identical to the byte to a gcc C version…"

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank you for your comment; "Ada benchmarks versus C++" is a good hint. It linked me to a site about testing different programing languages. However, the test was about gaming library; so, I can not acquire a comprehensive result. Are LISP and Prolog also good for image processing? Are they have an interface with Ada?

Comment: FYI, gaming involves image processing, especially the games with 3d look and lots of animation.

Comment: You will need to experience for yourself whether or not LISP and Prolog meet your definition of "good for image processing".

Comment: What kind of "processing" are you doing to the images?

Answer (score 4):

**Image processing/ML library in Ada:** I am not aware of any Ada native libraries for that, but you can quite easily use any similar library in C/C++.  Check also [Alire](https://alire.ada.dev/crates.html), it is a package manager for Ada.  It is quite young (release 1.0 was released in the last few months), but the community is very active.

**Processing speed:** like C or C++, more or less, definitively faster than Matlab or Python, since Ada (like C/C++) is compiled.
With Ada you can sometime have a small speed reduction (some %) because the compiler inserts checks to verify that there are no buffer overflows, values outside bounds, etc.  In an overwhelming number of cases, the robustness, security, easy of debug and maintenance that you get from that checks is definitively worth the small speed reduction.  If even that few % is critical to you, you can try *selectively disabling* the checks in the *most time consuming part* of your code.

**Is interfacing between Ada kernel and C/C++ for Machine learning, and Image processing lead to good speed?**
To be honest, this question is not perfectly clear to me. I am interpreting it as you are asking if you get good performances by using from Ada a C/C++ library for ML/Image processing.

Your mileage may vary, of course, but in general I expect the answer to be *yes*.  When compiled there is no overhead in calling C/C++ functions from Ada, you can have a very small one if you decide to write a "thick layer" that transforms the C-like interface (usually quite low level with pointers and stuff) into a more Ada-ish interface.  Usually the translation done by the thick layer amount to do some type casting and moving some data, therefore the overhead is minimal.

**About concurrence** I guess you mean using Ada `tasks` with the C/C++ library.  Well, in this case I guess much depends on your computer.  ML and Image processing are CPU-intensive tasks, therefore you can gain something only if you have more than one CPU on your computer (if the tasks did some I/O you could move one with a task while another is waiting).
**Beware:**  check that the C/C++ library is task-safe, that is, it can be used by two different tasks at the same time without risk of disrupting its internal structures.
If it is not task-safe, you can maybe use a protected object to provide a "task-safe layer" to your library.  In this case I wonder if it is worth the effort, since the library (that I expect will carry out most of the work) could be used only by one task at the time.

**Interface with Julia and Python**: Honestly I have no experience with this.  If Julia and Python have an interface for C code (and usually every script language nowadays does), then you can interface them with Ada too, maybe by using a small C "gateway."
One problem that sometimes I experienced with script-C interfaces is that they sometimes rely on C macros for constants or inline functions.  Of course, C macros are not visible to Ada and sometimes the simplest solution (IMHO) is to use a small C "gateway" that is able to "see" the macros.

Comment: Note that Python can also be compiled like C++ or Ada.  It isn't always interpreted, so one might look around to make sure it is actually slower in all contexts.

Comment: “definitively faster than Matlab or Python, since Ada (like C/C++) is compiled.” MATLAB is actually compiled, and it has been for something like 15 years. Weird how some of these misconceptions persist for so long.

Answer (score 2):

For the first step (loading your image into memory), you can use the GID open-source library:

https://gen-img-dec.sourceforge.io/

https://github.com/zertovitch/gid

Regarding the processing itself you'll get the same performance as C if you use GNAT.

Answer (score 1):

Others have broached the earlier questions.

For Julia interfacing, there are some user libraries, this one comes to mind:
http://www.dmitry-kazakov.de/ada/components.htm#Julia

For Python, AdaCore has some facilities in their GNATCOLL library:
https://www.adacore.com/gems/gem-106-lady-ada-kisses-python-part-2

Comment: I really disappointed. Ada language tutorial said it is good for multi-language programing. However, it doesn't interface with C++ or R or ... . The only choices are Fortran and C and COBOL (I think the last one is not counted).

Comment: @ALIN  it interfaces with C++ and Java as well.  The Ada Gnoga library interfaces with javascript and HTML5.  There's lots more options than you think.